# Маршрут на внешний адрес

Tags: linux, centos

Есть сервер на Centos 7 на нем надо прописать маршрут до внешнего адреса
Ввожу ip route add 194.85.18.40/32 via 10.52.2.22 dev eth0
Получаю ошибку
Error: any valid prefix is expected rather than "194.85.18.40/32 via 10.52.2.22"
Что неправильно?

Comment: 194.85.18.40, если хост. Класс сети здесь не нужен, т.е. без /32

Comment: Без /32 такая же ошибка

Comment: Что пишет route -n?

Comment: убери dev eth0.